# Google Drive Public File Permissions

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Let's say I have a public folder which is not discoverable. If I expose the File ID of one of the files for download, is it possible for an untrusted user to obtain a link to the folder which contains that file, or a link to other files within that folder? I've done a search on the Google APIs but haven't found anything relevant.

Edit:
Seems like some of you guys still don't get the question. So let me illustrate with a diagram. Let's say I have a public folder in Google Drive:

```
Folder A |
         |-- File X
         |-- File Y
         |-- File Z
```

So the question is, if someone else has the File ID of File X, which I'm fine with, then can he get the File ID of Folder A? Or the File IDs of Files Y and Z? That's where I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a file on Google drive it is just that public.

1. If you share the file with me,  then I have access to it.
2. If i install an application that has access to my google drive account the owner of the app has access to it (Really they ahve access to all my files)
3. If i give a copy of the link to my friend they can access it.
4. I can technically also see what directory the file is in.  I can then make a request to see what other files may be within this directory.  If the directory is public then I have access to that information.

Only the file you set to public will be accessible.

1. Files within the same directory as a public file will **not** be public.
2. The parent directory will **not** be public just because it contains a public file.

The point with public drive files is anyone can access them without permissions. The only security you have is that Tom on the street cant just do a search and find your file, or can they will it popup in google search someday?

Update file id:

If you expose the file id then i can take the file id and download the file using the API just like you can using a public api key or using the Google APIs explorer.  The file is public anyone can download it that has the id.   It was also possible in the past to take the file id and use that to create a URL for download directly though the Google Drive website.

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{FileID}/edit#gid=0
>
> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/{FileID}

This does not always work anymore mostly with files that are of type Google doc.

I can also use the file id to see what directory the file is in and request a list of files within that directory.

**Example Testing with a given file id**

> https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI?key={my api key}

or just use the try me on this page

[Files.Get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get)

Response

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI",
 "etag": "\"G9mQazc6pdRCuGfUPB_oyY074Ug/MTUxNTY5MzM4NjYxNA\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI",
 "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI&export=download",
 "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI/view?usp=drivesdk",
 "embedLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI/preview?usp=drivesdk",
 "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/image/png",
 "thumbnailLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_vX1BrFIsR-lVnFR1-VS9tp2toDLNfE6Cf1m3RGEIG7--VQfp53OiNbrnLC_rOGmqUbfn6QHQ7c=s220",
 "title": "splash.png",
 "mimeType": "image/png",
 "labels": {
  "starred": false,
  "hidden": false,
  "trashed": false,
  "restricted": false,
  "viewed": false
 },
 "createdDate": "2018-01-11T09:31:51.426Z",
 "modifiedDate": "2018-01-11T17:56:26.614Z",
 "markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
 "version": "8",
 "parents": [],
 "downloadUrl": "https://doc-0g-6o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/1mngaurn1r7pdnvlih02e6t9l8me2de5/3q2i7ak140vftlc9c96evgvnsmri4m4v/1517565600000/18429462472537742596/06030588225573437243/1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI?e=download&gd=true",
 "userPermission": {
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "etag": "\"G9mQazc6pdRCuGfUPB_oyY074Ug/WUHObW5vTApa-BsGvLisiOGqWbA\"",
  "id": "me",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI/permissions/me",
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user"
 },
 "originalFilename": "splash.png",
 "fileExtension": "png",
 "md5Checksum": "108e62ba72a0b33cb4bc7628e48d2e2c",
 "fileSize": "22375",
 "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
 "ownerNames": [
  "WU JUANG CHEN"
 ],
 "owners": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",
   "displayName": "WU JUANG CHEN",
   "isAuthenticatedUser": false,
   "permissionId": "18429462472537742596",
   "emailAddress": "XXXX@connect.hku.hk"
  }
 ],
 "lastModifyingUserName": "WU JUANG CHEN",
 "lastModifyingUser": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "WU JUANG CHEN",
  "isAuthenticatedUser": false,
  "permissionId": "18429462472537742596",
  "emailAddress": "xxxxx@connect.hku.hk"
 },
 "capabilities": {
  "canCopy": true,
  "canEdit": false
 },
 "editable": false,
 "copyable": true,
 "writersCanShare": true,
 "shared": true,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "appDataContents": false,
 "headRevisionId": "0B-l1jDyJ1EfRZERkZnJmcUZxRHlkUzk0bEx6bmhMUzd3WXdrPQ",
 "imageMediaMetadata": {
  "width": 375,
  "height": 812,
  "rotation": 0
 },
 "spaces": [
  "drive"
 ]
}
```

Analytics

1. I have your email address "emailAddress": "XXXX@connect.hku.hk" and name
2. A view link of the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI/view?usp=drivesdk as well as a download link for it.

Note: "parents": [], should contain the ID of the parent directory for this file.  I am going to assume that its either private or in your root directory.   If you say that the directory for this file is public i think its an awesome feature of google not to display this.

Which would mean that the answer is if you have the file id you dont necessarily get access to the folder id.

Comment: I'm sorry, but doesn't really answer the question, does it? Maybe I was unclear, switched the wordings of the question a bit.

Comment: Not exactly sure i see the difference but i have updated my answer to be more clear.   The fact is the file is public anyone can access it without permissions.   They just have to be able to find it with either a link to it or the file id.

Comment: @DalmTo Seems like you still haven't answered my question. I've edited my question again to make it more clear.

Comment: Umm if the **folder** isnt public then no one has access to the folder.   Thats kind of obvious i would think.   If you set a **file** public the *file alone is public nothing* else that would be a really bad security design on googles part if I set a file public and by default something other than just the single file was set to public.

Comment: @DalmTo Yes, but I've mentioned that the folder is public as well.

Comment: Ok so you have a public folder with a public file within it.    If you give me the file id of the public file.    I can then check that file and see what folder it lives in.    I can then request what files are within that folder finding the other files within that folder (because its also public).     I think you need to consider that there are creative people out there. If you create a public file and give the id to someone someone is going to find away to abuse this knowledge.   If you create a public api key you can test all this.   yourself trying to find out what information you can get.

Comment: @DalmTo Is that so! So let's say I give you a file with ID '1AzP6ISIrC8CvK3rTZfNBJ8qZL6LwcaSI', how would you find the ID of the folder it was in? Thanks!

Comment: Hows that, I removed your email address :)

Comment: Thanks!  I guess my setup sort of works then. I'll go scour the docs to see is there any user permission which specifically allows or disallows other users to get my file's parent, since it is indeed a public folder.